# SocketTimeoutException connecting to database on Linux Virtual Machine

Tags: java, linux, virtual-machine

Oracle NoSQL is a database that should be hosted on Linux, so I have a virtual Ubuntu running in Oracle VM VirtualBox. My host computer is running Windows 7.

I've got a bridged connection going, and I definitely am able to communicate between the two. With the database running on both machines, I can connect to the other machine's admin console, which runs on port 5001, through a web browser just fine. I can connect in that way using either the IP address of the machine on our network, or its network name.

From both machines, I can connect to that machine's database and use that database from a java program using either the IP address or the network name.

From the virtual machine, I can connect to and use my PC's kvstore using the network name, but I get a socketTimeoutException using the IP address. I believe that is due to a limit in the kvstore.

From my pc I cannot connect to and use the virtual machine's kvstore using the network name or the ip address. When I try to connect using the virtual machine's network name I get the following stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" oracle.kv.FaultException: Could not contact any RepNode at: [pc30129vm:5000] (11.2.2.0.26)
Fault class name: oracle.kv.KVStoreException
    at oracle.kv.KVStoreFactory.getStore(KVStoreFactory.java:123)
    at nosql.Test.main(Test.java:18)
Caused by: oracle.kv.KVStoreException: Could not contact any RepNode at: [pc30129vm:5000]
    at oracle.kv.impl.util.TopologyLocator.getInitialTopology(TopologyLocator.java:226)
    at oracle.kv.impl.util.TopologyLocator.get(TopologyLocator.java:85)
    at oracle.kv.impl.api.RequestDispatcherImpl.<init>(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:285)
    at oracle.kv.KVStoreFactory.getStore(KVStoreFactory.java:118)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: pc30129vm; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:632)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.list(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.kv.impl.util.TopologyLocator.getInitialTopology(TopologyLocator.java:175)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:75)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at oracle.kv.impl.util.registry.ClientSocketFactory.createSocket(ClientSocketFactory.java:300)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 9 more
```

I've tried running Nmap on that port on the virtual machine, and that seems to come back fine. With the nmap command:

```
nmap -p 5000 pc30129vm
```

I get the result:

```
Starting Nmap 6.25 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-03-18 14:51 Pacific Daylight Time

Nmap scan report for pc30129vm (192.168.0.25)

Host is up (0.0030s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE

5000/tcp filtered upnp

MAC Address: 08:00:27:44:A1:10 (Cadmus Computer Systems)


Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 11.74 seconds
```

I just can't figure out why I can't connect to and use the virtual machine's database. With a coworker's laptop which runs linux I was even able to connect, but for some reason the virtual machine seems to stymie my efforts.

Comment: What does "filtered" mean in the `nmap` STATE column ? :)

Comment: I don't actually know, but nmap.org tells me it means `Nmap cannot determine whether the port is open because packet filtering prevents its probes from reaching the port. The filtering could be from a dedicated firewall device, router rules, or host-based firewall software.`

Comment: Yes, you most likely have a firewall in place that prevents you from accessing that port. The firewall may protect the server and reject incoming connections to it or perhaps it prevents outgoing connections from your machine -- or both, worst case scenario.

Comment: When you can actually access a port, `nmap` reports "open" in the STATE column.

Comment: Well ... you were right. I thought I'd permanently turned that dumb firewall off, but it turned itself back on when I restarted the virtual machine! Thanks. You can put your response in an answer and I'll accept it if you want.

Comment: OK, I'm glad you solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments pasted as an answer:

You most likely have a firewall in place that prevents you from accessing that port. The firewall may protect the server and reject incoming connections to it or perhaps it prevents outgoing connections from your machine -- or both, worst case scenario.

When you can actually access a port, nmap reports "open" in the STATE column.